# Java - My file cannot be read and i cannot figure this out

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I am currently attempting to write this code and cannot understand why my file, `common-dictionary.txt`, won't read in. It has simple names like "aaron" and "address" for example, but the main problem is that it just isn't detecting it. It always ends with "the word was not found in the dictionary" even if it exists in file `common-dictionary.txt`. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code so far:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Project_12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String prompt = "Enter a word or 'quit' to stop: ";

        ArrayList<String> personalDictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Construct a Scanner to read user input from the keyboard.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Spell Checker");
        System.out.println("-------------");

        // Perform a priming read to get the first word.
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String word = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        // Enter the user input loop.
        while (!word.equals("quit")) {

            // Check if the word is in either dictionary.
            if (checkSpelling(word, personalDictionary, commonDictionary)) {
                System.out.println("The word is spelled correctly.");
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("The word was not found in the dictionary.");            
                System.out.println("Would you like to add it to your personal dictionary (yes/no)?");
                String response = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    word.toLowerCase();
                    personalDictionary.add(word);
                    Collections.sort(personalDictionary);
                    System.out.println("Word added. Enter a word to 'quit' to stop");
                }
            }

            // Get the next word from the user.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(prompt);
            word = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }

        keyboard.close();
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("common-dictionary.txt"));
            ArrayList<String> commonFile = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(scan.hasNextLine());
            {
                commonFile.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
            scan.close();
            return commonFile;
        }

    // Return true if word is in either array; otherwise, return false. Note 
    // that the arrays are sorted, so binary search can be used.
    public static boolean checkSpelling(String word, ArrayList<String> personal, ArrayList<String> common) {

    if (Collections.binarySearch(common, word.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (Collections.binarySearch(personal, word.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    }


    // Write the nonempty elements of an oversize array to a given file.
    public static void writeFile(ArrayList<String> personal)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("personal-dictionary.txt");
        Collections.sort(personal);

        int length = personal.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            writer.write(personal.get(i));
        }

        // Close the file; otherwise, the contents will be lost.
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("common-dictionary.txt"));` will assume that the file is located in the "current working directory", this is important, as this may not be the "current execution/installation directory".  Use something like `System.out.println(new File("common-dictionary.txt").exists())` to determine if the file can actually be found

Comment: You could also use `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` to print the working directory

Comment: I don't see you calling `readFile` within the main method, seems like you're just not loading your dictionary into the program.

Comment: @MichaelMurray where would I add the readFile method? It just seems to mess with the output when i insert it.

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like you need to call it to return the value for `commonDictionary` like `List<String> commonDictionary = readFile();`

Comment: @MichaelMurray sorry, but i'm not quite understanding. Do I need to call it in place of another line, or add it upon its own. Every time I call the readFile method the output  only returns "true" instead of the "correctly spelled" or "not spelled". This is quite difficult for me and I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The method `checkSpelling` always returns false because the `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary` is initialized as empty list: `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = new ArrayList<String>();`. In order to put the file's content into `commonDictionary` you have to set it to the list returned by the method `readFile()` which contains the words stored in the file: `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = readFile();`.

Comment: So I changed the `commonDictionary` variable in readFile to 'commonFile' because it was getting confusing, based on this information, what do you mean by **"you have to set it to the list returned by the method readFile() which contains the words stored in the file: ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = readFile();"** This is stumping me pretty bad, and I don't really know what to do.

Comment: The method `readFile()` reads the lines of a file and puts them into a list. This list is returned by the method. In order to get this list you have to call the method and assign it to a variable. Using `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = readFile();`, the list `commonDictionary` is given the list which contains the lines of the file.

Comment: When I replace the `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = new ArrayList<String>();` into the `ArrayList<String> commonDictionary = readFile();` its output is only "true" and I cannot figure out the problem past this, because I cannot see what could be causing nothing else to appear

Comment: What returns `true`? The method `checkSpelling`?

Comment: When I run the program its only output is "true' and I cannot figure out where its coming from or whats causing it

Comment: I tried the program myself and found the issue you were talking about: There is a semicolon after the while-loop `while(scan.hasNextLine());` so that that the code block under it isn't recognised as part of the while-loop. Because the position of the scanner's file reader is never changed using `scan.nextLine()`, `scan.hasNextLine()` is always `true` and an infinite loop is generated. Just remove the semicolon after the while-loop to fix it.